Account Aging Strike Out Amount For Vouchers Using
Assume there are 2 tables, 1 is payment and the other is deduction. Now the following query which I got from somewhere gives me following result



DeductionID
DeductionAmount
PaymentID
PaymentAmount
DeductionBalance
PaymentBalance




1
1000.00
1
500.00
500.00
0.00


1
1000.00
2
550.00
0.00
50.00


2
150.00
2
550.00
100.00
0.00


2
150.00
3
100.00
0.00
0.00



This all seems good but I need amounts which have been deducted i.e.



DeductionID
DeductionAmount
PaymentID
PaymentAmount
DeductionBalance
PaymentBalance




1
1000.00
1
500.00
500.00
500


1
1000.00
2
550.00
0.00
500


2
150.00
2
550.00
100.00
50


2
150.00
3
100.00
0.00
100



Following is the query
DECLARE @Deductions TABLE (DeductionID int IDENTITY(1,1),DeductionAmount money);

INSERT @Deductions (DeductionAmount) VALUES (1000),(150);

DECLARE @Payments TABLE (PaymentID int IDENTITY(1,1),PaymentAmount money);

INSERT @Payments (PaymentAmount) VALUES (500),(550),(100);

-- Preprocessing

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Deductions') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Deductions;

SELECT DeductionID, DeductionAmount, [from] = ISNULL(LAG([to],1) OVER (ORDER BY DeductionID),0), [to]
INTO #Deductions
FROM (SELECT *, [to] = SUM(DeductionAmount) OVER (ORDER BY DeductionID) FROM @Deductions) d;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ucx_DeductionID ON #Deductions (DeductionID);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Payments') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Payments;

SELECT PaymentID, PaymentAmount, [from] = ISNULL(LAG([to],1) OVER (ORDER BY PaymentID),0), [to]
INTO #Payments
FROM (SELECT *, [to] = SUM(PaymentAmount) OVER (ORDER BY PaymentID) FROM @Payments) d;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ucx_PaymentID ON #Payments (PaymentID);

-- Generate result set
-- Note that Deduction 2 is covered by Payments 3 AND 4.
-- Please check your figures in your expected result set

SELECT
    DeductionID, 
    DeductionAmount, --d.[from], d.[to],
    PaymentID, 
    PaymentAmount, --p.[from], p.[to],
    DeductionBalance = CASE WHEN d.[to] > p.[to] THEN 
                        d.[to] - p.[to] 
                    ELSE 
                        0 
                    END,
    PaymentBalance = CASE WHEN p.[to] > d.[to] THEN 
                    p.[to] - d.[to] 
                WHEN d.[to] IS NULL THEN 
                    PaymentAmount 
                ELSE 0 END
FROM #Deductions d
FULL OUTER JOIN #Payments p
    ON p.[from] < d.[to] AND p.[to] > d.[from]
ORDER BY ISNULL(d.DeductionID, 1000000), p.PaymentID;

Thanks
I tried to do it using available fields but failed to get amount.

Relevant article series: https://sqlperformance.com/2021/12/t-sql-queries/supply-demand-challenge

thanks @Charlieface this article helped me alot. my issue has been resolved. btw i cant accept ur answer as its comment

A link is not an answer. You're free to answer your own question.
